# TS video copied to MP4, missing 3 first frames when programmatically read (ffmpeg bug)

Tags: python, opencv, video, ffmpeg

Running:

```
ffmpeg -i test.ts -fflags +genpts -c copy -y test.mp4
```

for [this](https://mega.nz/file/JANmRTgR#6wtVXNIHoB9MGhCOBuv1oKIdl4o_adiWcI73R6ggusc) test.ts, which has 30 frames, readable by opencv, I end up with 28 frames, out of which 27 are readable by opencv. More specifically:

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -count_packets  -show_entries stream=nb_read_packets -of csv=p=0 tmp.ts
```

returns 30.

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -count_packets     -show_entries stream=nb_read_packets -of csv=p=0 tmp.mp4
```

returns 28.

Using OpenCV in that manner

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(tmp_path)
readMat = []
while cap.isOpened():
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not ret:
            break
        readMat.append(frame)
```

I get for the ts file 30 frames, while for the mp4 27 frames.

Could someone explain why the discrepancies? I get no error during the transformation from ts to mp4:

```
ffmpeg version N-111746-gd53acf452f Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 11.3.0 (GCC)
  configuration: --ld=g++ --bindir=/bin --extra-libs='-lpthread -lm' --pkg-config-flags=--static --enable-static --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libsvtav1 --enable-libdav1d --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-nonfree --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-cuvid --enable-nvenc --enable-libnpp 
  libavutil      58. 16.101 / 58. 16.101
  libavcodec     60. 23.100 / 60. 23.100
  libavformat    60. 10.100 / 60. 10.100
  libavdevice    60.  2.101 / 60.  2.101
  libavfilter     9. 10.100 /  9. 10.100
  libswscale      7.  3.100 /  7.  3.100
  libswresample   4. 11.100 /  4. 11.100
  libpostproc    57.  2.100 / 57.  2.100
[mpegts @ 0x4237240] DTS discontinuity in stream 0: packet 5 with DTS 306003, packet 6 with DTS 396001
Input #0, mpegts, from 'tmp.ts':
  Duration: 00:00:21.33, start: 3.400000, bitrate: 15 kb/s
  Program 1 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : Service01
      service_provider: FFmpeg
  Stream #0:0[0x100]: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(progressive), 300x300, 1 fps, 3 tbr, 90k tbn
Output #0, mp4, to 'test.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf60.10.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 300x300, q=2-31, 1 fps, 3 tbr, 90k tbn
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[out#0/mp4 @ 0x423e280] video:25kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 4.192123%
frame=   30 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=      26kB time=00:00:21.00 bitrate=  10.3kbits/s speed=1e+04x
```

### Additional information

The origin of the video I am processing comes from a continuous stitching operation of still images ts videos, produced by this class `update` method:

```py
import cv2
import os
import subprocess
from tempfile import NamedTemporaryFile
class VideoUpdater:
    def __init__(
        self, video_path: str, framerate: int, timePerFrame: Optional[int] = None
    ):
        """
        Video updater takes in a video path, and updates it using a supplied frame, based on a given framerate.
        Args:
            video_path: str: Specify the path to the video file
            framerate: int: Set the frame rate of the video
        """
        if not video_path.endswith(".mp4"):
            LOGGER.warning(
                f"File type {os.path.splitext(video_path)[1]} not supported for streaming, switching to ts"
            )
            video_path = os.path.splitext(video_path)[0] + ".mp4"

        self._ps = None
        self.env = {
            
        }
        self.ffmpeg = "/usr/bin/ffmpeg "

        self.video_path = video_path
        self.ts_path = video_path.replace(".mp4", ".ts")
        self.tfile = None
        self.framerate = framerate
        self._video = None
        self.last_frame = None
        self.curr_frame = None


    def update(self, frame: np.ndarray):
        if len(frame.shape) == 2:
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
        else:
            frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_RGB2BGR)
        self.writeFrame(frame)

    def writeFrame(self, frame: np.ndarray):
        """
        The writeFrame function takes a frame and writes it to the video file.
        Args:
            frame: np.ndarray: Write the frame to a temporary file
        """


        tImLFrame = NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".png")
        tVidLFrame = NamedTemporaryFile(suffix=".ts")

        cv2.imwrite(tImLFrame.name, frame)
        ps = subprocess.Popen(
            self.ffmpeg
            + rf"-loop 1 -r {self.framerate} -i {tImLFrame.name} -t {self.framerate} -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -y {tVidLFrame.name}",
            env=self.env,
            shell=True,
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        )
        ps.communicate()
        if os.path.isfile(self.ts_path):
            # this does not work to watch, as timestamps are not updated
            ps = subprocess.Popen(
                self.ffmpeg
                + rf'-i "concat:{self.ts_path}|{tVidLFrame.name}" -c copy -y {self.ts_path.replace(".ts", ".bak.ts")}',
                env=self.env,
                shell=True,
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
            )
            ps.communicate()
            shutil.move(self.ts_path.replace(".ts", ".bak.ts"), self.ts_path)

        else:
            shutil.copyfile(tVidLFrame.name, self.ts_path)
        # fixing timestamps, we dont have to wait for this operation
        ps = subprocess.Popen(
            self.ffmpeg
            + rf"-i {self.ts_path} -fflags +genpts -c copy -y {self.video_path}",
            env=self.env,
            shell=True,
            # stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
            # stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
        )
        tImLFrame.close()
        tVidLFrame.close()
```

Answer (score 5):

This is because the DTS time has a discontinuity:

You stated:

> Could someone explain why the discrepancies? I get no error during the
> transformation from ts to mp4:

But the error is here:

> [mpegts @ 0x4237240] DTS discontinuity in stream 0: packet 5 with DTS
> 306003, packet 6 with DTS 396001

Duration: 00:00:21.33, start: 3.400000

using `ffprobe -show_frames`

**pts** / **pts_time**

```
306000  3.4
306001  3.400011
306000  3.4
306001  3.400011
396000  4.4
306003  3.400033
396001  4.400011
396002  4.400022
396003  4.400033
396004  4.400044
486004  5.400044
576004  6.400044
666004  7.400044
756004  8.400044
846004  9.400044
936004  10.400044
1026004 11.400044
1116004 12.400044
1206004 13.400044
1296004 14.400044
1386004 15.400044
1476004 16.400044
1566004 17.400044
1656004 18.400044
1746004 19.400044
1836004 20.400044
1926004 21.400044
2016004 22.400044
2106004 23.400044
2196004 24.400044
```

Though, even if you use `-fflags +igndts`, I only get 29 frames. The problem itself is in the .TS file, and there is a DTS Discontinuity with the timestamps that you can see in those first frames.

After trying to get it to ignore timestamps, everything still yielded 29 frames for me instead of 30 with FFMPEG. There is probably something else I am missing, but I do not use FFMPEG heavily.

I tried what I could find at:

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#setpts_002c-asetpts

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#toc-Advanced-options

I tried with:

```
-fps_mode passthrough
```

29 frames

```
-vf "setpts='(RTCTIME - RTCSTART) / (TB * 1000000)'"
```

29 frames

```
-vf "asetpts=N/SR/TB"
```

29 frames

```
-copytb -1 -copyts -start_at_zero -fps_mode passthrough -dts_delta_threshold 1000000 -dts_error_threshold 1440000
```

29 frames

Also, please note that if you try using:

```py
def save_frames(file:str)->None:
    f = f_split(file)
    vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(file)
    for frame_num in range(vidcap.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT)):
        vidcap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_POS_FRAMES, frame_num)
        _, image = vidcap.read()
        cv2.imwrite(
            f"{f[0]}TempFileDirectory/{f[1]}_{str(frame_num).zfill(4)}.png", image
            )
    vidcap.release()
```

The total amount of frames being read from the video by OpenCV is only 21 frames, as OpenCV just reads what the file says is has. So that if you used the method above, it would only yield 21 frames. There is an issue with the pts timestamps in the .TS file itself so that the `TimeLength * FramesPerSecond = TotalFrames` calculation that was being queried by OpenCV to infer the total frame count, was way off.

Using the ubiquitous "while success" method, as you noted, does indeed yield the full 30 frames.

I would just not use FFMPEG to extract the frames themselves, and just rely on the OpenCV method, as this does not appear to be a bug in FFMPEG, but a feature of the encoding libraries to drop frames that have erroneous timestamps.

```py
import cv2

file = "./test.ts"

def f_split(f: str) -> list:  #  0: "X:/basedir/" , 1: "filename" , 2: "ext"
    return list([f[:len(f)-(f[::-1].find(chr(47))):],
                f[len(f)-(f[::-1].find(chr(47))):(len(f))-1-len(f[-(f[::-1].find(".")):])],
                f[-(f[::-1].find(".")):],]
                for f in[f.replace(chr(92),chr(47))])[0]
                #chr(92) is "\" backslash, and chr(47) is "/" forwardslash

def frame_extract(file: str) -> int:
    count = 0
    f = f_split(file)
    vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(file)
    (success, image) = vidcap.read()
    while success: # if reading a frame worked, and while it works:
        count += 1
        cv2.imwrite( # save the frame somewhere
            f"{f[0]}TempFileDirectory/{f[1]}_{str(count).zfill(4)}.png", image
        )
        (success, image) = vidcap.read() # check for another frame before loop restarts
    vidcap.release()
    return count

print(f"Frame count: {frame_extract(file)}")
```

> Frame count: 30

Comment: Thank you for the rather detailed answer, highly appreciate it. Do you mind also sharing why you think the timestamps are erroneous, given the fact that I only stitched still frames videos together, with the exact same framerate of 1 fps? That does not look like a feature to me..

Comment: @VasilisLemonidis seems to me like pts_time say that frame #3 is supposed to be displayed 0.000011 seconds *EARLIER* than frame #2, so it basically say `display frame #1, then frame #2, then frame #3 prior to frame #2`

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately don't know why it is happening, i suspect a vsync issue, but attempting to disable it with `-fps_mode passthrough` does not fix your problem, and vsync shouldn't really be applicable to `-c copy` anyway... However if we disable vsync and re-encode it, all 30 frames are intact (albeit re-encoded, and lossily re-encoded at that), this works:

```
ffmpeg -y -i test.ts -fps_mode passthrough test.mp4
```

you can add `-qp 0` to create a nearly lossless re-encoding, but that usually adds significantly more disk space (and the fact that you have to re-encode it anyway to just get all your frames is.. suboptimal)